# Validating two attributes at once in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, latitude-longitude

I have the following ViewModel;

```
public class MyViewModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required")]
    [Range(SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, ErrorMessage = "Keep location within map bounds")]
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required")]
    [Range(SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, ErrorMessage = "Keep location within map bounds")]
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I am using an OpenStreetMap as an input for these latitude and longitude values, and I want to add client-side and server-side validation using the attributes in the ViewModel.  I am creating two html input fields (both hidden).  When the form is submitted (and not setting a location), I am naturally getting "Location is required" twice.  How can I group these two attributes to be validated together?

View;

```
<form asp-area="" asp-controller="Report" asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="latitude" type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Latitude" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Latitude" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="longitude" type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Longitude" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Longitude" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a custom attribute to validate the coordinate pairs.

In your model I would remove the [Required] attribute and replace it with a custom validation attribute. The values can be set to a default in the model so that the initial view does not throw the errors initially. Your controller can then override the coordinates to whatever you want after the view is rendered.

```
public class MyCoordinateModel {    
    [Range(SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, ErrorMessage = "Keep location within map bounds")]
    [CustomCoordinate("Longitude", ErrorMessage = "{0} field has not been set.")]
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }

    [Range(SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, ErrorMessage = "Keep location within map bounds")]
    [CustomCoordinate("Latitude", ErrorMessage = "{0} field has not been set.")]
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }

    MyCoordinateModel()
    {
        Longitude = 0;
        Latitude = 0;
    }
}
```

The custom attribute would be something like this with the error message showing conditionally and custom to the property that is invalid:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | 
  AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomCoordinateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _requiredProperty;

    public CustomCoordinateAttribute(public double? requiredValue)
    {
         _requiredProperty = requiredValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
       ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var currentValue = (double)value;

        var property = 
            validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_requiredProperty);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified property name not found");

        var otherValue = 
            (DateTime)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        if ((currentValue == null) || (otherValue == null))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("None of the coordinates are defined");
        }

        if ((currentValue == null) && (otherValue != null))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(String.Format(
                ErrorMessageString, currentValue));
        }

        if ((currentValue != null) && (otherValue == null))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(String.Format(
                ErrorMessageString, otherValue);
        }

        if ((currentValue < 0) || (otherValue < 0))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Coordinates cannot be negative");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I also remove the range attribute and add it in the custom attribute instead?

Comment: I think the range attribute would also be restrictive on the default values of the class, so that would be a good idea to move it into the customized validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to validate before form submitting,here is a demo:

Action:

```
public IActionResult Verify(double? Latitude,double? Longitude)
        {
            if (Latitude==null||Longitude==null)
            {
                return Json("Location is required");
            }

            return Json(true);
        }
```

MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    [Range(SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, ErrorMessage = "Keep location within map bounds")]
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }

    [Range(SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SOME_RANDOM_COORDINATE, ErrorMessage = "Keep location within map bounds")]
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
  <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Report" asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="latitude" hidden asp-for="Latitude" class="form-control" value="1"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Latitude" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="longitude" hidden asp-for="Longitude" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Longitude" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" id="error"></span>
    </div>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
<script>
    
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Verify?Latitude=' + $("#latitude").val() + '&Longitude=' + $("#longitude").val(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "valid") {
                    $("#error").html(data);
                } else {
                    $('form').unbind().submit();
                }
            }

        })
        return false;
        
        
    })
   
</script>
}
```

result:
[image]